# Delete query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this simple code but it shows error. I dont know where I am going wrong.
It shows error in last line.

```
 linq_testDataContext db = new linq_testDataContext();
 var remove = from aremove in db.logins
         where aremove.username == userNameString && aremove.Password == pwdString
         select aremove;
 db.logins.DeleteOnSubmit(remove);
```

Answer (score 5):

`DeleteOnSubmit` takes a single object. You are passing an `IEnumerable<login>` to it. Use `DeleteAllOnSubmit` instead, or select a single object from your resulting collection, like this:

```
var remove = (from aremove in db.logins 
             where aremove.username == userNameString 
                && aremove.Password == pwdString 
             select aremove).FirstOrDefault(); 

if(remove != null)
{
    db.logins.DeleteOnSubmit(remove);
}
```

Comment: @philip now query is working fine but data is not deleted from table. it is still there..how can I fix this..Thanks

Comment: Run the debugger and look what is in that `remove` variable. I guess there is no element inside it, therefore nothing is deleted.

Comment: By the way: why do you check against the password in your query? I guess the username alone is disjunct from all others, is it?

Comment: sir I am just testing this query weather its working or not..I am writing linq for the first time... I am having same problem with insert...my query does ont show any chnages in database...

Comment: thats difficult, because we neither know your database nor the contents of it. Did you set a breakpoint before starting the debugger and set a watch to the variable `remove`? What are the contents of that collection at runtime?

Comment: Sir I have a small table having three columns...userid (int), username (nvarchar(50)), Password (nvarchar(50))
userid is primary key and is autoincrementing.
how to see contents of collections at runtime..

Comment: Get started reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx. Basically you set a breakpoint on the line where you make the `RemoveAllOnSubmit` call, then you run the debugger. It holds the execution of the program at exactly that line. Now you can move your cursor over the `remove` variable. You expand that tree, clicking on 'results view', you either see some `login` objects, or just an empty collection.

Comment: ok..sir..yes i set the DeleteAllOnSubmit() line on breakpoint and now I am debugging it...

Comment: when I move my cursor over remove variable it shows this:
(local varibale)IQueryable<login>remove

Comment: There is a plus sign right next to it, click it to expand the view. click the plus sign next to 'results view' and tell us what it shows there.

Comment: I mean results view is empty sir.

Answer (score 5):

you are missing foreach loop to delete all entity.

Use like below

```
var remove = from aremove in db.logins
     where aremove.username == userNameString && aremove.Password == pwdString
     select aremove;
```

and after that

```
foreach (var detail in remove)
{
    db.logins.DeleteOnSubmit(detail);
}
```

and at last

```
 try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Provide for exceptions.
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
db.logins.DeleteOnSubmit(remove);
```

Call [`DeleteAllOnSubmit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.deleteallonsubmit.aspx), like this:

```
db.logins.DeleteAllOnSubmit(remove.ToList());
```

Make sure to call `db.SubmitChanges()` afterwards.  You could use `.AsEnumerable()` as well, either or.  If it's a large delete operation though, you may want to think about bypassing LINQ in this case.

Comment: Thanks...yes its not showing any error but data is still in database...its not deleted...I refresh the database..still data is still there..how can I fix this

Comment: Good point Nick, I took it for granted to call `SubmitChanges` :)

Comment: I am calling submitchanges but still no change in database...
I tried to run debugger(F5)...but shows no error...here's my code...
 var remove = from aremove in db.logins
                         where aremove.username == "admin" && aremove.Password == "kk"
                         select aremove;

            db.logins.DeleteAllOnSubmit(remove);
            db.SubmitChanges();

Comment: @Ani - What value does `remove.Count()` have?

Comment: @Aani - Sorry, I meant to run it in the debugger when you're on the `DeleteAllOnSubmit()` line.  You can execute it in the immediate window, use Ctrl+Alt+I to bring it up.

Comment: I guess this is how i shd do....set the breakpoint on DeleteAllOnSubmit() line and then try to debug(F5)..isn't it sir??

Comment: @Ani - Correct, set a break point, when it lands on that line, Ctrl+Alt+I to open the immediate window, see what the result of `remove.Count()` is.

Comment: immediate window is blank sir.

Comment: @Nick after setting break point on that line and debuggin it. when I move my cursor over remove variable it shows this: (local varibale)IQueryable<login>remove

Comment: @Ani - Then that's the problem, your query isn't finding anything to delete...so nothing deleted.  Is it possible you need a case-insensitive query when selecting the user or something?

Comment: I double check its...all lower case..just now i deleted my data source an created a new one...now I put a break point on datacontext line...and checnked if its null or not.. and its null..

linq_testDataContext db = new linq_testDataContext();
db is null...where i am doing wrong

Comment: Now I have data till this line...I checked with break point it has that on this like.. remove has that line that i want to delete...but still no changes in database.
 db.logins.DeleteAllOnSubmit(remove);
after this line I am doing this.
       db.SubmitChanges();

Answer (score 2):

use this code its work

```
var remove = (from aremove in db.logins 
             where aremove.username == userNameString 
                && aremove.Password == pwdString 
             select aremove).FirstOrDefault(); 

if(remove != null)
{
     db.logins.Remove(remove);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the method first(), something like this:

```
var remove = 
    (from aremove in db.logins where aremove.username == userNameString 
    && aremove.Password == pwdString select aremove).first();

db.logins.DeleteOnSubmit(remove);
```

Answer (score 0):

***For good practices***

```
 private void DeleteCourse()
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32( txtSearch.Text);
            CourseDemoDataContext cdContext = new CourseDemoDataContext();
            course courseobj = cdContext.courses.Single(courses => courses.COURSE_ID == id);
            cdContext.courses.DeleteOnSubmit(courseobj);
            cdContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It will be worked for you.

```
linq_testDataContext _DbContext = new linq_testDataContext();
var remove = _DbContext.aremove.where(x=>x.username == userNameString && x.Password == pwdString).FirstOrDefault();
if(remove != null)
{
     db.logins.Remove(remove);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved by using where() and Tolist() of code..
.
Considering db.logins is a DATA TABLE and aremove representing DATA ROW in a table with username, Password representing the Columns to be checked..,
.
.
A linq can be written like this..,

```
db.logins.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(aremove  => aremove["username"].ToString() == "userNameString" && aremove["Password"].ToString() == "pwdString")
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(m => m.Delete());
```

Answer (score 0):

On .net7 or greater:

`ExecuteDelete` is much easier

```
(from aremove in db.logins
where aremove.username == userNameString && aremove.Password == pwdString
select aremove).ExecuteDelete();
```